# Android NestedScrollView stopNestedScroll not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I have 2 fragments inside the `NestedScrollView` and one fragment contains `RecyclerView` and another fragment contains `GoogleMap` and each fragment contains a text view as a title on top of it.

When I long tap on recycler view I am showing recycler view in full-screen view by changing its height to 100%.

Now I want to stop scrolling the title of RecyclerView's fragment but it is still scrolling the title when recycler view reached its last item.

This is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.myapp.common.CustomNestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true" />

    </com.myapp.common.CustomNestedScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

It looks like:

[image]

I tried to stop the scrolling by extending the CustomNestedScrollView with NestedScrollView like:

```
class CustomNestedScrollView : NestedScrollView {

    var isEnableScrolling = true

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyle: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyle) {}

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) {}

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {}

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        return if (isEnableScrolling) {
            super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev)
        } else {
            false
        }
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        return if (isEnableScrolling) {
            super.onTouchEvent(ev)
        } else {
            false
        }
    }
}
```

And setting the value from the activity when height is 100% like:

```
nestedScrollView.isEnableScrolling = !isFull
```

Also tried by stopping Scroll of NestedScrollView like:

```
if (isFull) {
        nestedScrollView.stopNestedScroll(ViewCompat.TYPE_NON_TOUCH)
    } else {
        nestedScrollView.startNestedScroll(ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL, ViewCompat.TYPE_TOUCH)
    }
```

Expected:
[image]

Comment: recyclerview has method  `setNestedScrollingEnabled(boolean enabled) ` try setting this to false.

Comment: Yeah I tried that but `setNestedScrollingEnabled(boolean enabled)` it is to make it smooth scrolling but not stops the scrolling